# Trying to update column with numbers from other table( Subquery returns more than 1 row)

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:quest_mail_loot_template (Table1) and quest_template (Table2).
They both have column "Entry" which is their primary ID key. They don't depend from each other.

Table2 has column RewMailTemplateId which can be null,but i need only `RewMailTemplateId<>0`.
I need to find rows where entry in both tables  are same and when it happens change each Entry in Table1 on number from column RewMailTemplateId from Table2.

I have tried to use this:

```
update quest_mail_loot_template Table1 set entry=(
   select RewMailTemplateId 
   from quest_template where RewMailTemplateId<>0) 
   where (
       select Table2.RewMailTemplateId 
       from quest_template TBL2 
       where TBL2.entry = TBL1.entry
   );
```

Seems sql is trying to update 1 field with all found numbers,but i need to update each entry for his own RewMailTemplateId,which are different numbers.

Any advice which operators at least should i use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE table1 a
JOIN table2 b
   ON a.entry = b.entry
AND b.RewMailTemplateId<>0 AND  b.RewMailTemplateId!=a.entry
SET a.entry = b.RewMailTemplateId
```

Or

```
UPDATE table1 a
JOIN table2 b
   ON a.entry = b.entry
SET a.entry = b.RewMailTemplateId WHERE  b.RewMailTemplateId<>0 AND  b.RewMailTemplateId!=a.entry
```

Comment: If they both have primary keys but dont match you could do ON a.entry=b.entry+whatever number you need to match,or minus.

Comment: I have tryed both variants,but [Err] 1062 - Duplicate entry '103-11422' for key 'PRIMARY'  I have used: select entry from quest_mail_loot_template GROUP by entry
 HAVING count(*)>1;   and   select RewMailTemplateId from quest_template GROUP by entry
 HAVING count(*)>1;    But this gave no results. I can't understand why there can be duplicates.

Comment: @user2879524 Post your tables schema.

Comment: I have understand problem. In table quest_mail_loot_template there are 4 rows with entry which equal to RewMailTemplateId from other table. If delete this 4 rows,then your query works. Is there any way to ignore them ? Something like if b.RewMailTemplateId=a.entry then don't update.

Comment: @user2879524 Check out my edit,but its better for a JOIN not to have duplicates on the joining columns,for clarity.

Comment: But even if  b.RewMailTemplateId=a.entry Then the update basically does nothing because that is want we want from it, SET b.RewMailTemplateId=a.entry.Are you sure those are the 2 column in question?

Comment: Tryed your last variant - still without deleting this 4 raws will be error about Duplicate entry. Anyway i just delete from before query and all fine. Thanks for help. That is ok result for my problem. Sad what i can't rep you.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is selecting all non-zero templates, not just the one associated with the quest_mail_loot_template entry. You need tow qualify it. Don't have all your column names, but something like this.

```
(
    select RewMailTemplateId 
    from quest_template 
    where RewMailTemplateId<>0
      And quest_template.??? = Table1.??? 
)
```